# How can I get a higher accelerometer sample rate

Tags: ios, ios9, accelerometer, iphone-6, uiaccelerometer

I know that this has been asked before, but I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to sample more then 100Hz with iOS 9 and iPhone 6 and 6s?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say (or the accelerometer update interval):

> The value of this property is capped to minimum and maximum values; the maximum value is determined by the maximum frequency supported by the hardware.

Asking for an update rate higher than the hardware supports is like asking for the laws of physics to be different: it's an interesting dream, but in *this* corner of *this* universe, it isn't going to happen any time soon.

Comment: Well, I understand that the accelerometer will actually sample faster than that, but is limited by the *software* to preserve battery life.  My question was not trying to understand your corner of the universe, rather to better understand if I could run the accelerometer to it's hardware limit. Sheesh.